# AJAX Check and update at specific time.

Tags: ajax

I'm new to Ajax, and i'm facing a problem. I got a html form and a database, the input is an integer. I want to check at every 5 seconds if the input changed. If so, I want to update the database. If not I want it to check again in 5 seconds. How do I do that in AJAX?

Comment: To do something every 5 seconds (assuming you're using JavaScript), you want to use the setInterval function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval. Within the setInterval function, you can check if the input has changed and make your AJAX call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setInterval` function to do your checking

```
 setInterval(function(){
    var value=$("#your_id").val();//textbox value
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "get", //send it through get method
        data:{value: value },
        success: function(response) {
            //Do Something
            //alert(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            //Do Something to handle error
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

In ajax.php you check that value

```
if(isset($_GET['value'])){
$value=$_GET['value'];
//select your old value from database suppose it as $old_value
if($value!=$old_value){
    //update your table using $value
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

usea global js variable

```
var gblPreviousTxtBoxValue = $('#txtboxid').val();
```

use setInterval function to call the function every 5 sec

```
setInterval(function(){
    var currentTxtBoxValue =$("#your_id").val();

    if(gblPreviousTxtBoxValue != currentTxtBoxValue) //check if current and previous textbox values are not equal
    {
     $.ajax({
        url: "yoururl",
        type: "post",
        data: { "textboxname": currentTxtBoxValue },
        success: function(response) {
            //Code
            },
        error: function(xhr) {
            //Do Something to handle error
        }
      });
     }
     gblPreviousTxtBoxValue = currentTxtBoxValue; //assign current value
    }, 5000);
```